What does Conv2D 32x32x3 actually mean?
I came across a paper which explains a CNN architecture (image attached) which contains Conv2D blocks represented by Conv2D MxMxN. I am having trouble understanding what it means in terms of kernel dimensions and the number of kernels.

Paper link

The dimensions 32x32x3 indicate there are 3 filters with size 32x32. Because you tagged tensorflow, here is how you could write this layer in tensorflow. Keep in mind the layer in the paper might include padding and other options, but this is how you can at least configure the kernel dimensions.
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters=3,
    kernel_size=(32, 32),
)


That's what I thought initially, but when you look at the architecture, it mentions multiple convolutional blocks with 3 filters and varying kernel sizes which I found odd because normally both kernel size and number of filters change as we go deeper in the network. Also having 3 filters right after the concatenation layer (output channels=4096) there seems to be a significant loss of information. Please correct me if I'm wrong

i agree it could have loss of information, but that's what it looks to be. the paper is very light on details of the model implementation.
